# How to change chart font-size in Britecharts React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am unable to change the font-size of the x and y-axis using Britecharts - React.  (see https://britecharts.github.io/britecharts-react/#bar).  From the docs it seems that the method is "labelsSize" but this is not currently working.  A forked codepen showing the issue is here: https://codepen.io/mvolny/pen/XWZrmXR.  Thanks.

```
const {Bar} = window['britecharts-react'];
const barData = [
  {
      name: 'Radiating',
      value: 2,
  },
  {
      name: 'Opalescent',
      value: 4,
  },
  {
      name: 'Shining',
      value: 3,
  },
  {
      name: 'Vibrant',
      value: 6,
  },
  {
      name: 'Vivid',
      value: 6,
  },
  {
      name: 'Brilliant',
      value: 1,
  },
];
const marginObject = {
  left: 100,
  right: 40,
  top: 40,
  bottom: 40,
};

ReactDOM.render(
<Bar
  data={barData}
  width={400}
  isHorizontal={true}
  margin={marginObject}
  labelsSize={50}
/>, 
document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: So, as I've found out
you have to set `enableLabels` and then `labelsSize` will work
however- this creates labels at the end of the bars, which doesn't seem like is what you want

I'm not entirely sure how to change the size of the text with britecharts though, since I haven't used it a lot. Hopefully, someone else can shed some light on it!

Comment: @StarnightFox Thanks for that.  Yes, I see now that labelsSize does only refer to labels being added to the ends of bars.  Still unable to change the font-size for x- and y-axis labels though.  Hoping someone else has experienced this before.

Answer (score 1):

Found this out asking around in the Brightcharts-React github page.  Basically, you need to target the elements of the chart via css.  See example for changing the font-size:

```
.tick text {
  font-size: 16px !important;
}
```

similarly,

```
.vertical-grid-line {
display: none !important;
}
```